# Hazelcast server connection priority for a client

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast client and two hazelcast Servers in a cluster which contain single replicatedMap per server.

I am giving 2 hazelcast server nodes to client to read from replicatedMap.

Can I give connection priority to one server and read my data from that server as long as the connection is alive?

To clarify, 
    Let's say there are MasterServer, SlaveServer and Client.

Can we force Client to connect MasterServer for all replicatedMap operations if there is connection between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off [smart routing](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#java-client-operation-modes) and [force your client](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-smart-routing) to connect to a specific member. 
This way, your client will direct **all operations** to a single member. 
However, if you want to direct **only ReplicatedMap operations**, there is no option for that.

Comment: Can we route all operations to second member if first one shuts down with this strategy?

Comment: Client will connect to another member if the first one shutdowns. However, there is no guarantee which one will be the second member because for the second connection, it will use the member list that is received from the first member.